# Anaconda Navigator Crashes On Initialization (Python Has Stopped Working)

Tags: python, anaconda

Whenever I try to start the anaconda navigator, it crashes and a Python has stopped working error box appears.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Updating pyqt didn't seem to help. The problem still persists.

Edit 2: I tried reinstalling Anaconda too but that didn't help either.

Comment: check: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/4808.  And perhaps share what environment you are running in.

Comment: I am using the base environment and none of the solutions in the link work, sometimes the navigator starts for a second and crashes and sometimes it crashes on the initialization screen.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try updating pyqt. It fixed my problem. See [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10088).

Comment: it worked in my case. It happened after I install some big packages, maybe it can't be supported by older pyqt GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and I tried below 2 options to resolve this,
1: uninstalling and installing again,
2: updating pyqt using command "conda install -c anaconda pyqt" in Anaconda Prompt.
2nd option I tried with normal user as well as Admin user but that also didn't work and the finally i thought, it could be because of my Anti Virus (Quick Heal), which is blocking Navigator to execute properly.

Hence I tried opening Anaconda Prompt and executed command "jupyter notebook" to launch Jupyter, which finally worked for me. If first 2 steps are not working for you, please see if any Anti Virus is installed in your machine and if that is the case, try using Anaconda Prompt.